# A function that sums cell values by conditions in R

Tags: r, sum, conditional-statements

How to create a function that would check the condition from x3, x4, ... and sum each values cells (in x1, x2, ...) from df2 to df1 according to the conditions it checks from columns in df2 (x3, x4, ...)? The combinations of conditions are unique, name and order of column df1=df2. Thank you very much.

Example

```
df1 
x1  x2  x3      x4    x5
1   5   1100    2016  string1
2   6   2100    2016  string2
3   7   1100    2017  string3
NA  8   2100    2017  string4
7   4   3100    2017  string5
                
df2 
x1  x2  x3      x4    x5
3   NA  1100    2017  string3 
4   8   2100    2017  string4
2   5   1100    2016  string1
1   7   2100    2016  string2
                
new_df1 
x1  x2  x3      x4    x5
3   10  1100    2016  string1
3   13  2100    2016  string2
6   7   1100    2017  string3
4   8   2100    2017  string4
7   4   3100    2017  string5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is combining the dataframes using `rbind` and then using `dplyr` to `group_by` your condition columns and summing the rest of the columns using `summarise(across(everything(), sum, na.rm = T))`

```
df1 <- readr::read_table("
x1  x2  x3  x4
1   5   1100    2016
2   6   2100    2016
3   7   1100    2017
NA  8   2100    2017
7   4   3100    2017
")
df2  <- readr::read_table("
x1  x2  x3  x4
3   NA  1100    2017
4   8   2100    2017
2   5   1100    2016
1   7   2100    2016
")

library(dplyr)

rbind(df1, df2) %>%
  group_by(x3, x4) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), sum, na.rm = T)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(order(colnames(.)))

#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#>      x1    x2    x3    x4
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     3    10  1100  2016
#> 2     6     7  1100  2017
#> 3     3    13  2100  2016
#> 4     4    16  2100  2017
#> 5     7     4  3100  2017
```

Comment: Thanks. This would certainly work, unfortunately I have several dozen variables, i.e. I suppose I would have to create many columns with the mutate statement. Then, when I generate more tables with other column names, I would have to rewrite the statements. I meant more of a function that checks each cell and if it finds the same conditions, then it does the sum.

Comment: Now I try it by putting everything into one df, denoting in the new column rows from df1 „A“, df2 „B“, and looking for a way to sum them if the conditions match. It's probably not ideal, but I'm trying a solution that my skills are enough for now.

Comment: @Marek Alright, I changed the answer to a more generic solution. Does that work for you?

Comment: Great, it works as I need, thank you. I forgot only one thing, one variable is character, I had to delete it, otherwise it could not load the data frame.